# React-Router-dom :- Cannot read property 'string' of undefined at Object.../node_modules/react-router-dom/es/BrowserRouter.js

Tags: react-router

I have used create-react-app for creating a new working repository for react and i wanted to add some Routing paths using react-router-dom.

This is my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PostsIndex from './components/posts_index';
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDom.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<div>
<Switch>
<Route path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
</Switch>
</div>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And this is my posts_index.js file

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class PostsIndex extends Component {
render(){
return(
<div>Posts Index </div>
)
}
export default PostsIndex;
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: where does this error come from ? " Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
"

Comment: inisede my chrome console window. I know i am doing everything is right but still i dont know why this error is popping up.

Comment: no way :D I mean what file ? what line ?

Comment: not sure it's related but there is some typo here => "</BrwoserRouter>"  instead of "</BrowserRouter>"

Comment: No No actually i mistyped here but it is correctly written in my text editor. And i updated the question to show where the error is coming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Router cannot read property string of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696157/react-router-cannot-read-property-string-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed. I just updated my react-router-dom from 4.0.0 to 4.2.2.

Comment: plus 1 for your Q&A, it helped me fix my react issue

Answer (score 1):

This was how I fixed this particular error at my end.

- I updated my yarn version to the latest (v1.7.0 at this time) by downloading the installer from [yarn's website](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)
- Then I ran `yarn add react-router-dom --save`
- Restarted my application with `yarn start`

And away the error went. If you use `npm` for dependency management, I believe the same should apply while replacing `yarn` with `npm`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be working on my end.

Only things I had to adjust was the `ReactDom` to `ReactDOM` and a missing closing parenthesis in posts_index.js

Working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/nkvjqrvpwj

Comment: I apprecitate this But I am using Prettier-atom as default pluging so those paranthesis are the by default plugins which prettier provides us that is not the issue here but i think Prop-types is the main issue i am facing here

Comment: I can only go on the issues I see and can be replicated. Maybe you could send more info on the error, stack trace, dependency versions or anything else to help if you haven't figured it out already.